# Response.Redirect only sent 1 message

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm writing an SMS Function for our application.There's no error but its not meeting my expectations.
Using dataset i am getting multiple Mobile Numbers,then i need to pass a messaage to all those mobile numbers.

1.Using Response.Redirect only 1 message is sent and others not sent.(after 1st message sent it goes to that page)

Part of the coding below

```
DataSet DistDs = _distsms.GetAllDistributionList(UnitId, isShot, gameId, animalTypeId);
if(DistDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{   
    ContactNo = Convert.ToInt32(DistDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ContactNumber"]);
    foreach (DataRow row in DistDs.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        if (row["ContactNumber"].ToString() != "")
        {
            try
            {
                Response.Redirect("http://sms.gatewaysite.com/api/mt?msisdn=" + row["ContactNumber"].ToString() +
                                  "&body=" + msgOut + "&sender=" + shortcode +
                                  "&key=ertyertyer&product_id=4563456&operator=" + oppp + "&country=aaaaa");
            }
            catch(Exception ee)
            {
                string a = ee.Message;
                //continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check out description of [Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.100).aspx) on MSDN - maybe it is not the method you need. It is not clear what you are trying to achive with the code (which behaves exactly as you coded it).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov let's say dataset returns 2 rows then i take that 2 Mobile numbers(msisdn) and using response.redirect it send mesage to all those numbers.But only 1 message sent..

Comment: Response.Redirect does not send SMS or anything it just immediately returns 302 responce with location you gave as argument. I *don't know* if you need to use this call, but as your sample stands it behavior is compeletely expected. Mayby you need to send request from server as answers suggest (using `WebClient`/`HttpWebRequest`)...

Answer (score 1):

`Response.Redirect` does just that - it redirects the entire response.

For what you're trying to do, use `HttpWebRequest`

Answer (score 0):

it's bad way to send the data to the remote server. try using Web service calls or Web Api calls. where you can send data in JSON format. AFIK you are ending the Response stream.

alternatively you can invoke WebRequest via [`HTTP WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)

From MSDN

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/PostAccepter.aspx ");
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";
            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close ();
            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close ();
            dataStream.Close ();
            response.Close ();
```